# Mysql query to sort and merge two tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables in my mysql database called forum_topics and forum_replies.
I am looking to have an overview of the latest posts / replies added, like this: http://prntscr.com/6ixtz4

to do so, i need a way to makee it sort by the time in both tables, and if a forum_reply is in the result it need to get its topic from the forum_topics.

How can i make this work? I have no mysql query to referer to to make this work.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_topics` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `thread` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `creator` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `innlegg` text NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `locked` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `deleted` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_replies` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topicid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `reply` text NOT NULL,
  `deleted` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;
```

exampledata:

```
 in table forum_topics

id |topic| time|
1  | test | 10
2  |  test2 | 29



   in table forum replies:
id | topicid | time |

1   |  1   | 18
2   |  2   | 28
```

As in this example i would like the outcome to be sorted something like this:

```
10
18
28
29
```

if forum_replies is one of the results it would need some data from forum_topics, but if forum_topics is one of the results it wouldnt need any data from the forum_replies.

The topicid is the id from the forum_topics of the topic that the reply is a response to.

So in the end i want to create the example output as in the image.

EDIT:
it would be a result containing in following order:
    10
    18
    28
    29

Comment: How is  reply 2 @ time 28 made to topic 2 before topic 2 @ time 29 existed?

Comment: @Misunderstood if i get your question right, you are asking how it will check its topicname?

topicid is the id from topic table.

Comment: topic id=2 time is 29.  Reply id=2 time is 28 before time 29 when topic 2 was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I have to say the table structure of a forum post is incorrect. In your case, you will be very hard to sort a post based on topic and reply. I would suggest a table structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_topics` (
  `tid` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, // Topic ID
  `tsubject` varchar(255) NOT NULL, // Topic Subject
  `level` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `creator` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `innlegg` text NOT NULL, // I don't know what this means ...
  `locked` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `deleted` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  PRIMARY KEY (`tid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`tid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_posts` (
  `pid` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `pcontent` text NOT NULL, // Post Content
  `isauthorpost` int(1) NOT NULL, // Optional: If this is the first post of the topic
  `deleted` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`pid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;
```

So now you will have a topic id to follow by the first. And you can just search for all replies with `ORDER BY pid`, for the topic details, you can use `LEFT JOIN forum_topics` or `INNER JOIN` to finish.

Comment: Sorry if i misunderstood. but would that you said be able to sort it by the forum_posts and forum_topics, there the forum_topic would be before forum_post in the result?

thanks in advance. I will look into your reply and comment here.

Comment: When you implement with the table structure like me. If this is a new topic. Simple create two SQL commands `INSERT INTO forum_topics VALUES ('', '$tsubject', '', '$userid', '', '', '')` and get last insert id of forum_topics. The second query is `INSERT INTO forum_posts VALUES ('', '$tid', '$userid', 'time()', '$pcontent', '1', '')`. When you list all replies, you can use `SELECT p.*, t.subject, t.level, t.creator, t.innlegg, t.deleted AS tdeleted FROM forum_posts p, forum_topics t WHERE p.tid = t.tid ORDER BY pid ASC`

Comment: as for your query i get something simular to: http://prntscr.com/6iy67l

would it be able to get something like:http://prntscr.com/6iy6lv ( first the topic since its created before the reply, and then the reply including the info of the topic?)

Comment: I am sorry as I gave you a wrong SQL code to fetch posts. First you will need to load the status and subject of the topic, that should be `SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE tid=$tid` and then you should get only 1 row. Once you finished handling your data, you can now fetch the post contents. That would be `SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE tid=$tid ORDER BY pid ASC`. Now you will have all replies (include the first post).

Comment: but what if i only want the 5 latest results, no matter what if its a topic or reply? lets say i post two topics,  first topic one and then two replies to that, then topic 2and then one reply to that, then i would get it sorted by the creation time first.

topic1, reply1, reply2,topic2,reply3

since i am only going to use it to show overveiw of the latest in forums.
( reply`s are containing topic data, but no topic is containing reply data)

Comment: So in these 5 latest results, what you want to fetch? with the topic subject and topic details or just post contents? If you need both: `SELECT p.*, t.subject, t.level, t.creator, t.innlegg, t.deleted AS tdeleted FROM forum_posts p, forum_topics t WHERE p.tid = t.tid ORDER BY pid DESC`. If you only need post contents: `SELECT * FROM forum_posts ORDER BY pid DESC`, finish.

Comment: I want them ordered within the creation of it , so a topic thats created before a reply will be one of the results. I would like to fetch the topic whenever the result is a reply. as for now i only thing i think i need from topic within the reply is the subject.

i want it to be able to use the results to say new topic : test1
new reply on topic: test1 with the details. if you see what i mean.

Comment: first the topic ( if its created before the reply etc), then the reply with the fetch ( so when a topic is created and a reply, it will first contain the topic, then in next result the reply. kinda those two tables ordered by time.

Comment: So if this is a reply, you also need to show the topic details right? That means you need both. You will get all info you needed.

Comment: Thats correct yes. but the topic ( if created first) has to be on its own result, then the replies for that etc.

thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I want to make sure if you are preferring something like this. You have 2 topics, one have 1 reply and another have 2 replys. You want to list 5 latests topics and its replies (all replies or limited?). Or you only need to list the topics?

Comment: well. i want the 5 latest whatever, it could be 4 topic 1 reply,  3 topic 2 reply, 5 replies, whatever  5 last enteries in those tables no matter if its a reply or a topic. if it is a reply it has to get the topic merged,

Comment: In that case, `SELECT p.*, t.subject, t.level, t.creator, t.innlegg, t.deleted AS tdeleted FROM forum_posts p, forum_topics t WHERE p.tid = t.tid ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 1` will work for you.

Comment: but http://prntscr.com/6jf2zr , dont i need the topic itself as an result itself, and then the other?

Comment: As you needed 5 latest topics and it contents, the SQL has returned both for you to handle. So whatever it is a new thread or a reply, it always returns the subject of the topic.

Answer (score 1):

By loading the data in the example data sets, this will get the time from both tables, but sort the time from both as if they were in one table.   The below query gets the results, and then orders them in order of time.  Since both tables have the same structure, you can "union" them together as if they were one table and sort by time using "order_by"

```
select time
from forum_topics
UNION
select time
from forum_replies
order by time
```

Note:  I was able to load both tables in the above request but without the last line on each.  In other words I trimmed the part referring to the engine, and then just created the tables, and then entered the data provided..

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I was using the example data provided.  I was able to load both tables using the dump provided just by removing the last rows (referring to `ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT` etc.   I then loaded in the values under "exampledata" and was able to get the outcome requested.  I apologize if I misunderstood the question

Comment: Please edit your answer and place the additional information there.

Comment: Thank you Jay, good point.  I added some comments and explanation.